# Modify the WordPress admin bar CSS?

Tags: admin-bar

I want to remove how it adds 32px to the top of the HTML tag. It's dumping it there with a STYLE tag right at the end with !important.

It's damn impossible to override it, because there are no hooks or HTML and wordpress is setting it with like 5 css rules :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably produced by [`_admin_bar_bump_cb()`](http://queryposts.com/function/_admin_bar_bump_cb/).

From quick look at code it includes following instructions [inline in `WP_Admin_Bar` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L48):

> To remove the default padding styles from WordPress for the Toolbar, use the following code:
>
> `add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => '__return_false' ) )`;

Answer (score 1):

Check out David Walsh's solution:

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```

https://davidwalsh.name/remove-wordpress-admin-bar-css

This way you can still show the admin bar, but implement your own CSS!